# Angular 1.6.1 Dynamic loading Html with routeProvider triggerrs no controller this.$onInit

Tags: angularjs

I build a small app with angular an added the routeProvider to change my ContentView. The Switching betwenn my different htmls works and i can use cars and functions in my html.

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

angular.module("mainApp").config(
        [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
                function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

                $routeProvider.when("/", {
                    templateUrl : './page1.html',
                    controller : 'con1'
                }).when("/stuff", {
                    templateUrl : './page2.html',
                    controller : 'con2'
                }).when("/404", {
                    templateUrl : "./errorPage.html"
                })
                // else 404
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo : "/404"
                });
            } ]);
```

I added the Functions:

```
this.$onInit = function() {console.log("test"); };
```

Do Stuff when my controller is in the Init Mode. (Note: I added this pattern in a other project as well but in this newly project it wont load this.$onInit)

I'm Using Angular 1.6.1 as Webjar and  .

Any Ideas why it wont work?

Comment: Does the same code works only in one project but not in other? In which controller have you added `$onInit` lifecycle hook, can you post some code of the controller? Can you clarify your question a bit?  Does it look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aygqcgeb/2/)?

Comment: My other (first project) which implemented the same pattern calls the init function of the controller if the asinged html is loaded. And this project wont call it . kind of wierd.

Comment: Isn't it called somewhere manually like `this.$onInit();`? Have you checked my answer and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aygqcgeb/9/) example?

Comment: Were you able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not writing answer sooner. Yes you guys where right that the lifecyle wont call init if the routingProvider calls the Controller.

I solved it by manuelle triggering the init. I done that by adding the controller to the main body (container) with data-ng-controller="myController"

This calls init on pageload. Kind of hacky but it works great.

Answer (score 1):

[Life-cycle hooks were introduced for directive/component controllers.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

They will not fire for the controllers used in `$routeProvider` mappings. 
You can take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aygqcgeb/9/) and see the output in the console.